# Vulnerabilities list in Spring boot 3.0.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am planning to upgrade services from spring boot 2.2.6 to 3.0.2. I want to know if latest spring boot version has any new vulnerabilities and if all old vulnerabilities have been fixed in the spring boot latest version? Where can I get this information?
Note : I can see list of 57 vulnerabilities from maven repository in 2.2.6 version, but it did not list any vulnerabilities for 3.0.2 version.  While spring might have fixed direct vulnerabilities, there can be few vulnerabilities which are coming from transitive dependency.
Is there a way to find all vulnerabilities coming from direct and transitive dependencies ?

Comment: 3.0.2 is the newest version that just came out. It's very unlikely for the newest version to have any known vulnerabilities or there would be a newer version.

Comment: While spring might have fixed direct vulnerabilities, there can be few vulnerabilities which are coming from transitive dependency. 
Is there a way to find all vulnerabilities coming from direct and transitive dependencies ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is not easy, because we don't know all your used (sub-)dependencies. And an answer can be outdate in a couple of hours/days/weeeks ...

But you can lookup the dependencies manually with the new MavenCentral-website.
An example: When you search for "Spring JPA", then you will find this site: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/3.0.2/jar

And there is button to view the OSS-index which is pointing to this site:
[image: Image of OSS-index at MavenCentral]
https://ossindex.sonatype.org/component/pkg:maven/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa@3.0.2

Or, just make the upgrade and let your IDE resolve all the vulnerabilities automatically.
IntelliJ does it very well:
[image: Image of pom.xml in IntelliJ with warning]